# Get the index of the values of one vector in another?

Tags: r

I would guess this is a duplicate, but I can't find that so here goes...

I'd like to return the index of second in first:

```
first = c( "a" , "c" , "b" )
second = c( "c" , "b" , "a" )
result = c( 2 , 3 , 1 )
```

I guarantee that first and second have unique values, and the same values between the two.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an R function for finding the index of an element in a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577727/is-there-an-r-function-for-finding-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-vector)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Getting indexes of values is what `match()` is for.

```
 first = c( "a" , "c" , "b" )
 second = c( "c" , "b" , "a" )
 match(second, first)
 [1] 2 3 1
```

Comment: mdsummer - thanks!  the second part wasn't a questions, I was just stating some bounds to the problem (edited to make that more clear).  your solution works great!

Comment: w00te: in the R sources, [R]\src\library\base\R\match.R and [R]\src\main\match.c

Comment: clear question, clear answer! That's very nice and very rare example!!! :-) +1 +1

Answer (score 4):

I was solving related problem, selecting the elements of a vector based on a pattern. Lets say we have vector 'a' and we would like to find the occurrences of vector 'b'. Can be used in filtering data tables by a multiply search patterns.

```
a=c(1, 1, 27, 9, 0, 9, 6, 5, 7)
b=c(1, 9)

match(a, b)
[1] 1  1 NA  2 NA  2 NA NA NA
```

So match() it is not really useful here. Applying binary operator %in% is more convenient:

```
a %in% b
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

a[a %in% b]
[1] 1 1 9 9
```

Actually from the match() help %in% is just a wrap around match() function:

```
"%in%" <- function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another not efficient solution with `which` and `sapply`:

```
sapply(second, function(x) which(first==x)[1])
```

for every element of the `second` returns the first index found in `first`. if no match found NA is returned for that element