# How to find indices of element in one vector in other vector R

Tags: r

I have two vectors, let's say

```
a <-  c('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3')
```

and

```
b <- c('Q10', 'Q13', 'Q1', 'Q1', 'Q40', 'Q2', 'Q2', 'Q2')
```

Now I want to find the indices of the elements in `a` in `b`. So the result should be `[3, 4, 6, 7, 8]`. I tried to to it with `match(a, b)`, but this results in only the first occurrence of `a` in `b` so `[3, 6]`.

Does anyone know how to do this in R?

Comment: Could you please post your sample vectors in valid R syntax? E.g., `a = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3")`

Comment: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169388/5325862) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7530765/5325862)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
a <-  c('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3')
b <- c('Q10', 'Q13', 'Q1', 'Q1', 'Q40', 'Q2', 'Q2', 'Q2')

which(b %in% a)

[1] 3 4 6 7 8
```

Comment: Just to add to your answer for OP. ``match()`` was not working because ``match()`` returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its first argument in its second as read in the R Documentation.