# Position of elements from one vector in another vector with R

Tags: r

I wish to create a `vector` holding the position of `elements` from one `vector` in another `vector`.  This is similar to the following questions:

[Get the index of the values of one vector in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530765/get-the-index-of-the-values-of-one-vector-in-another)

[Is there an R function for finding the index of an element in a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577727/is-there-an-r-function-for-finding-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-vector)

The `match` function in base `R` works in the simplest case, shown here:

```
a <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
b <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
desired.output <- c(1,3,5,7,9)
match(b,a)
#[1] 1 3 5 7 9
```

However, `match` does not appear to work in more complex cases shown below.  I might need a combination of `which` and `match`.   In every case I am considering so far a value in `b` does not appear more often in `b` than in `a`.  I need a base `R` solution.

```
a <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
b <- c(1,2,2,3,4,5)
desired.output <- c(1,3,4,5,7,9)

a <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
b <- c(1,2,2,3,4,4,5)
desired.output <- c(1,3,4,5,7,8,9)

a <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
b <- c(1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5)
desired.output <- c(1,3,4,5,7,8,9,10)

a <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
b <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5)
desired.output <- c(1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10)

a <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
b <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
desired.output <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

Comment: 1) write a function that finds an index of a n-th occurence of a number in a vector 2) for every value in b, apply the function to a, while counting the occurences 3) put the values into the vector by result <- c(result, newValue) 4) Profit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the given cases `pmatch` will give the desired result. `match` in combination with `make.unique` will also work. If speed matters `split` could be used or a function using `Rcpp` is possible. Have also a look at [Efficiently match all values of a vector in another vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76382756).

```
pm <- function(x, y) {
    a <- split(seq_along(x), x)
    b <- split(seq_along(y), y)[names(a)]
    b[lengths(b)==0] <- NA
    b <- unlist(Map(`length<-`, b, lengths(a)), FALSE, FALSE)
    `[<-`(b, unlist(a, FALSE, FALSE), b) }

Rcpp::sourceCpp(code=r"(
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>

using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector pmC(NumericVector a, NumericVector b) {
  IntegerVector idx(no_init(a.size()));
  std::unordered_map<float, std::queue<int> > lut;
  for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i) lut[b[i]].push(i);
  for(int i = 0; i < idx.size(); ++i) {
    auto search = lut.find(a[i]);
    if(search != lut.end() && search->second.size() > 0) {
      idx[i] = search->second.front() + 1;
      search->second.pop();
    } else {idx[i] = NA_INTEGER;}
  }
  return idx;
}
)")
```

```
a <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
b <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
pmatch(b,a)
match(make.unique(as.character(b)), make.unique(as.character(a)))
pm(b,a)
pmC(b,a)
#[1] 1 3 5 7 9

a <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
b <- c(1,2,2,3,4,5)
pmatch(b,a)
match(make.unique(as.character(b)), make.unique(as.character(a)))
pm(b,a)
pmC(b,a)
#[1] 1 3 4 5 7 9

a <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
b <- c(1,2,2,3,4,4,5)
pmatch(b,a)
match(make.unique(as.character(b)), make.unique(as.character(a)))
pm(b,a)
pmC(b,a)
#[1] 1 3 4 5 7 8 9

a <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
b <- c(1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5)
pmatch(b,a)
match(make.unique(as.character(b)), make.unique(as.character(a)))
pm(b,a)
pmC(b,a)
#[1]  1  3  4  5  7  8  9 10

a <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
b <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5)
pmatch(b,a)
match(make.unique(as.character(b)), make.unique(as.character(a)))
pm(b,a)
pmC(b,a)
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  7  8  9 10

a <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
b <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
pmatch(b,a)
match(make.unique(as.character(b)), make.unique(as.character(a)))
pm(b,a)
pmC(b,a)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```