# r - Sampling list according to another vector

Tags: r, sampling

Consider two vectors :

```
 R> l
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
 R> s
 [1] "b" "d" "f"
```

I cannot hard-code the indexes to be removed from the sampling.
How can I sample elements from `l` that are not present in `s`?

Comment: Use `?sample` and `?setdiff`: along the lines of `sample(setdiff(l,s), ....)`

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
l <-c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
s <- c("b", "d", "f")
l2 <- l[!l %in% s] # elements present in "l" and not in "s"
sample(l2, 10, replace = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found it using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577727/is-there-an-r-function-for-finding-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-vector)

```
sample(l[-c(match(s, l))])
```

PS : Sorry, for asking before searching thoroughly.

**EDIT :-**

For the vectors :

```
R> l <- c(1:5000)
R> s <- c(100:1100)
```

I ran the micobenchmark :

```
R> microbenchmark(func(l, s), sample(l[-c(match(s, l))], 10), times=1000L)
```

Here, func() is defined as follows :

```
R> func <- function(l, s) {
    l2 <- l[!l %in% s] # elements present in "l" and not in "s"
    return(sample(l2, 10, replace = TRUE))
}
```

The microbenchmark returned:

```
Unit: microseconds
                          expr   min    lq  mean median    uq  max neval cld
                    func(l, s) 218.7 221.3 234.1  222.1 229.5 2937  1000   a  
sample(l[-c(match(s, l))], 10) 222.5 226.9 238.8  227.8 235.7 2933  1000   a
```

I guess, their performance is quite comparable.

Comment: As you can see, there are many alternatives.  It might be fun to do a time test:  create a couple large `l` and `s` vectors, say 1000 elements, and run each of the  answers supplied inside `microbenchmark` .