# find var in a data frame and return next element in same row

Tags: r, dataframe

ultimately, I need to search column 1 of my data frame and if I find a match to `var`, then I need to get the element next to it in the same row (the next column over)

I thought I could use`match` or `%in%` to find the index in a vector I got from the data frame, but I keep getting `NA`

one example I looked at is 
[Is there an R function for finding the index of an element in a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577727/is-there-an-r-function-for-finding-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-vector), and I don't understand why my code is any different from the answers.

so in my code below, if I find `b` in column 1, I eventually want to get 20 from the data frame.

What am I doing wrong?  I would preferr to stick to `r-base` packages if possible

```
> df = data.frame(names = c("a","b","c"),weight = c(10,20,30),height=c(5,10,15))
> df
  names weight height
1     a     10      5
2     b     20     10
3     c     30     15
> vect = df[1]
> vect
  names
1     a
2     b
3     c
> match("b", vect)
[1] NA
```

Comment: `vect` is a data frame.  Try `vect = df[[1]]` or `with(df, weight[match("b", names)])`

Comment: I thought I tried `df[[1]]` before, but yea, both of those work perfectly.  Thanks for showing me how to retrieve the data i need in one line.  Impressive!

Comment: Just to add another alternative: `df[df$names == "b", "weight"]`