# Trying to Write a For Loop that finds "TRUE" in rows

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm just trying to run a for loop that identifies which row numbers register as TRUE and prints it in the console.

```
 Holidays <- c("TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE")


 newvector <- for (i in 1:length(Holidays))
         {
             if (i == TRUE)
               print(i)
    }
```

Comment: What programming language is this? `boolean` is not a programming language.

Comment: Sorry, R. Fixed that.

Comment: That's better. It's not necessary to tag it in the title, just the tags themselves. That way people can find it and answer it.

Comment: `newvector <- grep("TRUE", Holidays)`

Comment: Don't assign your `for` loop, it doesn't return anything. Delete `newvector <-` and your code will print the values.

Comment: Also note that the character string `"TRUE"` is different from the boolean value `TRUE`. If your input is `Holidays <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)`, then that is good. And you can just do `which(Holidays)`.

Comment: If I remove the variables it prints [1] 1, which isn't correct?

Comment: Oh, also you should be testing if `Holidays[i] == TRUE` - `i` is just a number.

Comment: you are looping through integers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... so your logical has to evaluate at `Holiday[i] == "TRUE` instead of `i==TRUE`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to store which rows are TRUE preallocate an empty vector and bind it in the loop.

If you really have `TRUE` and `FALSE` as strings, do the following

```
Holidays <- c("TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE")
store = c()

for (i in 1:length(Holidays)){
             if (Holidays[i] == "TRUE") # here you want to see whether the element inside Holiday is equals "TRUE"
              store = c(store, i) # store vector you give you which rows are "TRUE"
    }
```

However, if you have actual logical entries in `Holidays`, then the correct syntax should be

```
Holidays <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
store = c()

for (i in 1:length(Holidays)){
             if (Holidays[i] == TRUE)
              store = c(store, i)
    }
```

However, as @Badger mentioned, there is no need to loop here. You can easily get the indices using `which`

```
store = which(Holidays %in% TRUE)
```

Comment: Best answer so far - to complete it you should also mention the difference between `TRUE` and `"TRUE"`.

Comment: sure, I just supposed he had actual strings, updating answer

Comment: Functionally it answers the question, but the question is still why use a loop at all?

Answer (score 2):

So using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577727/is-there-an-r-function-for-finding-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-vector) as a guide, the command below will get a vector of index numbers from the Holidays vector that match "TRUE":

```
true_indexes = which(Holidays %in% "TRUE")
print(true_indexes)
```

Comment: Another way: print(which(Holidays == T))

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** Please disregard my answer, it is not correct, as it had been pointed out to me.

===========================================================================

Your problem is that you store `TRUE` and `FALSE` as strings, not as booleans.

Instead of

```
Holidays <- c("TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE")
```

You should have:

```
Holidays <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

The rest of your code should work.

Comment: That's not a problem. Check 'TRUE' == TRUE

Comment: I guess you're right, @ManishSaraswat, I stand corrected. Learned something new today :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do it with a for loop ?
If you change cour mind you can do it with which. Works with non boolean, too

```
newvector <-which(Holidays == "TRUE")
```

Comment: Thanks. I am a newbie and I was just very stubborn about pulling off a for loop, haha. For my own amusement.