# getting value using keyvalue

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, key-value

I have the following keyvalue dataframe

```
keyval =  data.frame(key = c('facebook',  'facebook mai - android', 
         'facebook mai - ios', 'facebook remarketing','facebook ig', 
         'app - android', 'bing - sem broad', 'bing - trademark', 
         'google - sem broad' , 'google - trademark' , 'google display', 'pla', 
         'google retargeting') ,
          val = c(6,21,20,7,9,21,5,19,3,17,3,12,4))
```

and would like to use an `ifelse` statement to access the value when it corresponds but I'm not sure of how to write the second argument.

```
the_value_i_want =  ifelse(data$Publisher %in% keyval$key , 
                            notsurehowtowrite this part ,'error'),
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577727/is-there-an-r-function-for-finding-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-vector

Answer (score 1):

I think `ifelse` is not needed.

Subset `data` by the results of `data$Publisher %in% keyval$key`:

```
data[ data$Publisher %in% keyval$key, ]
```

This will return all the rows matching `Publisher` in `key`.

edit: Because your question is a bit unclear, you might want just the value instead of the whole data frame. If this is the case then:

`data[data$Publisher %in% keyval$key,]$val`

will return the `val` variable.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `match`; here is an example:

```
# Sample data
data <- cbind.data.frame(Publisher = c("facebook", "google display", "other"));

data$the_value_i_want <- keyval$val[match(data$Publisher, keyval$key)];
data;
#       Publisher the_value_i_want
#1       facebook                6
#2 google display                3
#3          other               NA
```

Comment: currently having this error though
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.

Comment: @teo93 I'm not using `mutate` (or any `tidyverse`/`dplyr` function) anywhere; so your error originates from somewhere else, and has nothing to do with the base R code above.