# Recode with a variable number of cases in R

Tags: r

I am creating a function that takes a list of user-specified words and then labels them as a number depending on the order of the number in the list. The user can specify different list lengths.

**For example:**

```
myNotableWords<-c("No_IM","IM","LGD","HGD","T1a")

aa<-c("No_IM","IM","No_IM","HGD","T1a","HGD","T1a","IM","LGD")
aa<-data.frame(aa,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

**Intended Output**

```
new<-(1,2,1,4,5,4,5,2,3)
```

Is there a way of maybe getting the index of the original list and then looking up where the each element of the target list is in that index and replacing it with the index number?

Comment: `match(aa, myNotableWords)`

Comment: [Is there an R function for finding the index of an element in a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577727/is-there-an-r-function-for-finding-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the `factor` functionality of R?

A "factor data type" stores an integer that references a "level" (= character string) via the index number:

```
myNotableWords<-c("No_IM","IM","LGD","HGD","T1a")
aa<-c("No_IM","IM","No_IM","HGD","T1a","HGD","T1a","IM","LGD")

aa <- as.integer(factor(aa, myNotableWords, ordered = TRUE))

aa
# [1] 1 2 1 4 5 4 5 2 3
```

Comment: That is freakin' genius

Answer (score 1):

```
new <- c()
for (item in aa) {
  new <- c(new, which(myNotableWords == item))
}
print(new)
#[1] 1 2 1 4 5 4 5 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `data.frame`; the syntax shouldn't change. I prefer using `data.table` though.

```
library(data.table)
myWords <- c("No_IM","IM","LGD","HGD","T1a")
myIndex <- data.table(keywords = myWords, word_index = seq(1, length(myWords)))
```

The third line simply adds an index to the vector `myWords`.

```
aa <- data.table(keywords = c("No_IM","IM","No_IM","HGD","T1a",
                         "HGD","T1a","IM","LGD"))
aa <- merge(aa, myIndex, by = "keywords", all.x = TRUE)
```

And now you have a table that shows the keyword and its unique number.