# How to sort a vector and print Top X value when the value is flat?

Tags: r

R language : How to sort a vector and print Top X value when the value is flat ?

If I have a vector like

```
v <- c(1,2,3,3,4,5)
```

I want to print the TOP1~TOP3 values.

So I use:

```
sort(v)[1:3]
[1] 1 2 3
```

In this case,TOP3 have 2 value

what I want to print is:

```
[1] 1 2 3 3
```

and their index

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it:

```
v[v %in% sort(v)[1:3]]
# [1] 1 2 3 3

# following up OP's comment, if you want ordered outcomes:
# sort(v[v %in% sort(v)[1:3]])
```

Comment: If
 v <- c(2,3,3,1,4,5)
the result will be 
[1] 2 3 3 1

Comment: Then, you can sort it again: `sort(v[v %in% sort(v)[1:3]])`

Comment: You can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577727/is-there-an-r-function-for-finding-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-vector). Please make sure to clarify your questions so you don't need to iterate again and again with follow-ups.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `top_n` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(v) %>% top_n(-3)

#  v
#1 1
#2 2
#3 3
#4 3
```

this returns a dataframe, if you want a vector `pull` it

```
data.frame(v) %>% top_n(-3) %>% pull(v)
#[1] 1 2 3 3
```