# Obtain index of the first element of the repeated value in a vector in R

Tags: r, vector, subset

How can we in `a`, obtain the index of the first element of the repeated value (index of first `1`, first `2`, first `3` ...)?

```
a <- c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 2), rep(3, 1), rep(4, 2))

desired.output <- c(1, 4, 6, 7)
```

Comment: Essentially answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577727/is-there-an-r-function-for-finding-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-vector

Comment: Also `sapply(unique(a), function(x) which.max(x == a))` but there are much better answers already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is `tapply`

```
as.vector(tapply(seq_along(a), a, FUN = `[`, 1))
#[1] 1 4 6 7
```

---

Or using

```
which(!duplicated(a))
```

Or with `which` and `diff`

```
which(c(TRUE, !!diff(a)))
```

Or when the vector is not numeric

```
which(c(TRUE, a[-1] != a[-length(a)]))
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option is `match`

```
match(unique(a), a)
# [1] 1 4 6 7
```

From `help('match')`

> match returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its first argument in its second.