# How to find element index when element is determined from quantile function?

Tags: r, indexing, quantile

How can I find the index of an element, when the element is determined using `quantile()`?
The `match()` and `which()` solutions from this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577727/is-there-an-r-function-for-finding-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-vector) do not work (they return NA), and I think they don't work because of rounding issues.

In the case that the quantile result is averaged/interpolated across two indices, can I specify if it takes the lower/higher index? My data `x` will always be sorted.

Example Dataset (Obviously the 0 and 1 quantiles here are just the min and max, they are just shown for a sanity check)

```
x <- c(0.000000e+00,9.771228e-09,5.864592e-06,3.474925e-04,9.083242e-04,2.458036e-02)
quantile(x, probs = c(0, 0.5, 1))
          0%          50%         100% 
0.0000000000 0.0001766785 0.0245803600
```

How do I find the indices for these quantiles? Here, the indices are `1,??,6`.
And I guess the median is the average of two indices, so can I specific that it returns the first or second index?

Comment: Which index are you trying to find? What is your expected output for the given data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `type=4` which uses linear interpolation of the empirical cdf (i.e. considers the actual median).

```
x <- c(0.000000e+00,9.771228e-09,5.864592e-06,3.474925e-04,9.083242e-04,2.458036e-02)
(q <- quantile(x, probs=c(0, 0.5, 1), type=4))
#           0%          50%         100% 
# 0.000000e+00 5.864592e-06 2.458036e-02 
match(q, x)
# [1] 1 3 6
x[match(q, x)]
# [1] 0.000000e+00 5.864592e-06 2.458036e-02
```

Other example:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- runif(1e3)
(q <- quantile(x, probs=c(0, 0.5, 1), type=4))
#           0%          50%         100% 
# 0.0002388966 0.4803101290 0.9984908344 
match(q, x)
# [1]  92 174 917
x[match(q, x)]
# [1] 0.0002388966 0.4803101290 0.9984908344
```

Comment: It just occurred to me it might be a `type=` issue, and then I logged in and saw your solution. This is so helpful, thank you

Comment: @a11 Haha, great coincidence, you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Use `findInterval` ?

```
x <- c(0.000000e+00, 9.771228e-09, 5.864592e-06, 3.474925e-04,
       9.083242e-04,2.458036e-02)
findInterval(quantile(x, probs = c(0, 0.5, 1)), x)
#[1] 1 3 6
```

Comment: Do you know why it says the 50th %tile is in position 3, but the quantile function returns 0.0001766785, rather than 5.864592e-06, for the 50th %tile?

Comment: `findInterval` gives the closest index before the number exceeds. `x - quantile(x, probs = 0.5)` might help to understand.

Comment: I think maybe this is a different question, but I don't understand why `quantile(x, probs = 0.5)` returns 0.0001766785. From the `x` dataset, it looks like the median should be 5.864592e-06, right?