# How to find indices of values present in a vector in R?

Tags: r

For eg. I have a vector of different colors,

`x = c("blue", "green", "red", "yellow", "green")`

I want to find the indices of the elements with `value = "green"`, which in this case would be 2 and 5.

Comment: It is not an `R` list (by syntax)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an R function for finding the index of an element in a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577727/is-there-an-r-function-for-finding-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-vector)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
> which(x == "green")

[1] 2 5
```