# Create loop for partial string matching of two vectors

Tags: r

**match(x,y) doesn`t work because of partial string matching**

I tried every possible solution from [Is there an R function for finding the index of an element in a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577727/is-there-an-r-function-for-finding-the-index-of-an-element-in-a-vector), but either I get back only NAs or integer(0)

I created two vectors.

First vector(x):

```
 x
 [1] "    scharfkantig"        "t:"                      "pat aht an 36 üz distal"
 [4] " seit paartagen"         "36 vipr++"               " perk-"                 
 [7] "üz bilfuird"             " pat"                    ""                       
[10] "pat knirscht"            " schiene empohlen"       " pat meldet sich.."
```

And a small part of my second vector(y):

```
y
[1] "01"                                  "beobachten"                         
  [3] "hkp"                                 "hkp"                                
  [5] "abform kiefer"                       "abform bissfix"                     
  [7] "opt elek abform"                     "vipr"                               
  [9] "perk"                                "oberfl anästh"                      
 [11] "anästh"                              "vest inj"                           
 [13] "duraphat aufge"                      "empfindliche stelle aufgetragen"    
 [15] "üz"                                  "duraphat"
```

Now I want to know the index of the elements of **y** matching with first vector.

The matches between both are in the first vector **x** elements (3,5,6,7) and in **y** (8,9,15).

Output should be **(8 9 15)**.

I tried it with a for-loop:

```
for(i in y) {
 x1 <-  grep(y,x)
 print(x1)
}
```

But my output looks like:

```
...
integer(0)
integer(0)
integer(0)
integer(0)
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Thank you very much!

The hole dataset of vector y is:

```
dput(y)
c("01", "beobachten", "hkp", "hkp", "abform kiefer", "abform bissfix", 
"opt elek abform", "vipr", "perk", "oberfl anästh", "anästh", 
"vest inj", "inj sept blau", "cx pulpennah", "infiltration", 
"injektion", "infil", "l1", NA, NA, "gezeigt zu achten", "putzdruck", 
"mhu", "gezeigt", "pat gezeigt", NA, NA, NA, "pzr", "psi sbi api", 
"dentalhygiene", NA, "duraphat aufge", "empfindliche stelle aufgetragen", 
"üz", "duraphat", "temp verschluss", "bmf blutstillung", "cp", 
"blutstillung", "bmf", "visco gel", "spanngummi anl", "fllg", 
"fllng", "f1", "f1", "f2", "fllg 2", "fllng 2", "f2 sät", "tetric flow", 
"f3", "fllg 3", "fllng 3", "mdv", "f4", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"st verank", NA, "metallprimer oberfläche", "monobond plus beh", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "ze rausschrauben", "zahnersatz raus", 
"Schraube rausgeholt", "ekr", "entf wurzelstift", "teilkrone abgestrahlt", 
"labor abgestrahlt", "wbf durelon", "wbf relyx", "wbf", "relyx wieder", 
"schraubenzugang clip flow", "verblendung repapieren", "komposit verblendet", 
"wiederherstellung", "cp", NA, "pulp", "vite", NA, "trep1", "trep", 
NA, "wk", NA, "med", "wf", "x1", "extraktion zahn", "ex", "x2", 
"ex", "wurzeln entf", NA, NA, "ost1", "osteotomie", "wunde stillen", 
"blutung", "gelamtamp", "drucktamponade", "nbl1", "nbl2", "exc", 
"exz1", "exz2", "pla0", "pla", "trep", NA, "wr1", "wr", "wr2", 
"hem", "reimpl", "ri", NA, "zy3", "zy", "zy1", "sms", "knr", 
"alv", "pla2", "pla", "pla3", NA, "germ", "ost2", "dia", "op kontrolle", 
"nach op", "wundheilung gut", "wundheilung", "alveogyl wunde", 
"naht entfernt", "naht entfernen", "wunde spülen", "wundinfektion", 
"fex", "naht", "nähen", "genäht", "xn", "staging grading", 
"ttm", "04", "psi", "chx spülung", "dontisolon auftgetragen", 
"mundschleimhaut", "donti", "donti aufgetragen", "chx", "chx gel", 
"sk", "prov eingeschliffen", "prot schleifen", "ds entfernt", 
"sk entfernt", "druckstelle entfernt", "druckstelle", "kante geglättet", 
"k entf", "grob vorkont", "zst", "belag", "beläge", "zahnstein", 
"zst entfernt", "belag entfernt", "polieren", "primer entf", 
"zst", "belag", "beläge", "zahnstein", "zst entfernt", "belag entfernt", 
"polieren", "primer entf", NA, "aita", "aitb", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "interims klammern aktiviert", 
"klammern aktiviert", NA, "Impl befestigt", "locato polymerisiert", 
"polymerisiert", "palawit", "locatoknopf", "impl abgegangen", 
NA, "einschrauben drehmoment teflon clip", "wbf durelon", "wbf relyx", 
"wbf", "relyx wieder", "prov hergestellt", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "wieder bef prothese", "prothese ausgearbeitet", 
"prothese poliert", "klammern aktiviert", "prot poliert", "bruchrep", 
"rep bruch", "reparatur", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "rö", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "rö", "rö2", "opg", "dvt")
```

Comment: Use `match(x, y)`.

Comment: try `pmatch(x, y)`? Also, can you provide a reproducible data set with `dput`?

Comment: I don't know why but pmatch also didn't work. It just returns NAs and a "7" at indexnumber 35.

Comment: After `for(i in y)` you should search `i`, not `y`: `x1 <-  grep(i,x)`.