# Find position of matching elements of one vector in another

Tags: r, performance, indexing, match

I have two very long vectors:

```r
a <- sample(1e+08L, size = 1e+09L, replace = TRUE)
b <- sample(1e+08L, size = 1e+09L, replace = TRUE)
```

I want to generate an integer vector `r` of length `length(a)` such that `r[i]` is the index of `a[i]` in `b`.

I tried `pmatch(a, b)` but it is very slow.  Is there a more efficient way?

---

Desired output for a small example:

```r
a <- c(1, 3, 5, 7, 8)
b <- c(3, 1, 7, 8, 5)
f(a, b)
## [1] 2 1 5 3 4
```

Comment: Is there a perfect matching between a and b? That is every element in a is also present in b? Or can some elements have no matches? Can they have multiple matches? What then?

Comment: @user2974951 all elements of b are in a but not vice versa

Comment: Why `pmatch` here? `match` seems to be working the same

Comment: We must be clear here: `pmatch` is for _partial string matching_, `match` is for exact integer matching. Consider that `pmatch(1L, 100L)` returns `1L` simply because the first character in `"100"` is `"1"`. All of the answers here should be edited to exclude `pmatch` to avoid spreading this misconception about its purpose.

Comment: See also: [Is there an R function for finding the index of an element in a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5577727/10488504)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the objective is just to `match()`, then we can use:

```
cppFunction('IntegerVector matchC(NumericVector x, NumericVector table) {
  IntegerVector out(x.size(), NA_INTEGER);
  for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < table.size(); j++) {
      if(x[i] == table[j]) {
        out[i] = j + 1;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return out;
}')
```

Answer (score 4):

Your question mentions `pmatch`, which performs partial matching of character vectors, but it seems like you want `match`, which performs exact matching of integer and other vectors.

`match` is faster, but even faster than `match` is `fastmatch::fmatch`:

```r
match(b, a)
fastmatch::fmatch(b, a)
```

Adding to the benchmarks:

```r
library(fastmatch)

set.seed(1)
a <- sample(1e5, 1e5)
b <- sample(1e5, 1e4)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  match = match(b, a),
  fastmatch = fmatch(b, a),
  check = "identical", 
  times = 100L)
```

```
Unit: microseconds
      expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
     match 9439.020 9500.602 9659.7537 9519.6260 9555.0090 12394.546   100
 fastmatch  367.606  376.134  398.4347  382.0175  399.1145   614.467   100
```

Answer (score 3):

Benchmark:

```
library(fastmatch)   #fmatch
library(data.table)  #merge
library(collections) #hash

Rcpp::cppFunction('IntegerVector matchC(NumericVector x, NumericVector table) {
  IntegerVector out(x.size(), NA_INTEGER);
  for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < table.size(); j++) {
      if(x[i] == table[j]) {
        out[i] = j + 1;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return out;
}')

Rcpp::cppFunction('IntegerVector matchC2(const std::vector<int>& x, const std::vector<int>& table) {
  IntegerVector out(x.size(), NA_INTEGER);
  std::unordered_map<int, int> lut;
  lut.max_load_factor(table.size()/(double)*max_element(table.begin(), table.end()));
  lut.reserve(table.size());
  for(int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) lut[table[i]] = i+1;
  for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    auto search = lut.find(x[i]);
    if(search != lut.end()) out[i] = search->second;
  }
  return out;
}')

set.seed(1); a <- sample(1e5, 1e5); b <- sample(1e5, 1e4)
    
bench::mark(
  match = { match(a, b) },
  fmatch = { fmatch(a, b) },
  zx8754.merge = {
    merge(data.table(x = a, rnA = seq_along(a), key = "x"),
          data.table(x = b, rnB = seq_along(b), key = "x"),
          all.x = TRUE)[order(rnA), rnB] },
  sotos.Rcpp = { matchC(a, b) },
  GKi.Rcpp = { matchC2(a, b) },
  user2974951.hash = {
    h = dict(seq_along(b), b)
    sapply(a, h$get, default = NA)},
  "jblood94.[" = `[<-`(NA_integer_, b, seq_along(b))[a]
)
```

Result

```
  expression            min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
  <bch:expr>       <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 match              1.86ms   1.99ms   479.      951.3KB     7.98   240     4
2 fmatch             1.03ms   1.12ms   896.     393.34KB     6.00   448     3
3 zx8754.merge       4.71ms   5.02ms   181.       8.05MB    31.6     92    16
4 sotos.Rcpp          2.38s    2.38s     0.420    1.22MB     0        1     0
5 GKi.Rcpp         891.93µs  945.6µs  1018.     393.16KB     7.98   510     4
6 user2974951.hash 127.58ms 133.66ms     6.85     3.44MB    30.8      4    18
7 jblood94.[       227.28µs  244.8µs  3193.     800.85KB    48.0   1597    24
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can create a hash table (which doesn't exist in base R for some reason) then you can look up the indices of the elements in `b` for every element in `a` in O(1) time.

```
> library(collections)
> h=dict(seq_along(b),b)
> sapply(a,h$get,default=NA)
[1] 2 1 5 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert to *data.table* and *merge*:

```
library(data.table)

merge(data.table(x = a, rnA = seq_along(a), key = "x"),
      data.table(x = b, rnB = seq_along(b), key = "x"),
      all.x = TRUE)[order(rnA), rnB]
# [1] 2 1 5 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated based on GKi's comment.

If `a` and `b` are both positive integer vectors, with `length(b)`~`max(b)`, indexing will be even faster:

```
library(fastmatch)   #fmatch

intmatch1 <- function(a, b, maxb = max(b)) {
  B <- rep(NA_integer_, maxb)
  B[b] <- seq_along(b)
  B[a]
}

intmatch2 <- function(a, b) {
  `[<-`(NA_integer_, b, seq_along(b))[a]
}

set.seed(1); a <- sample(1e5); b <- sample(1e5, 1e4)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  match = match(a, b),
  fmatch = fmatch(a, b),
  intmatch1.1 = intmatch1(a, b),
  intmatch1.2 = intmatch1(a, b, 1e5),
  intmatch2 = intmatch2(a, b),
  check = "identical")
#> Unit: microseconds
#>         expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
#>        match 2543.101 2593.901 2800.5480 2646.7020 2732.801 7627.601   100
#>       fmatch 1107.801 1181.551 1272.0101 1201.4510 1261.601 5928.401   100
#>  intmatch1.1  316.401  375.451  418.3490  402.3005  424.351  658.001   100
#>  intmatch1.2  327.000  386.851  522.8529  401.7505  456.901 5670.001   100
#>    intmatch2  277.402  347.051  424.7270  359.6010  382.902 5026.601   100
```

Comment: A shorter version could be `\`[<-\`(NA, b, seq_along(b))[a]`

Comment: Currently this will only work for integers > 0. So `min` of `a` and `b` might need to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Another Rcpp variant based on @Sotos but using `unordered_map` to find the index.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('IntegerVector matchC2(const std::vector<int>& x, const std::vector<int>& table) {
  IntegerVector out(x.size(), NA_INTEGER);
  std::unordered_map<int, int> lut;
  lut.max_load_factor(table.size()/(double)*max_element(table.begin(), table.end()));
  lut.reserve(table.size());
  for(int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) lut[table[i]] = i+1;
  for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    auto search = lut.find(x[i]);
    if(search != lut.end()) out[i] = search->second;
  }
  return out;
}')

matchC2(a, b)
#[1] 2 1 5 3 4
```